# How to translate “single-threaded” in a software documentation?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

As the question states: How would you translate *single-threaded* in a software documentation? *Einzel-gethreadet* sounds kinda weird to me. The sentence I would like to translate is the following:

> The object is not thread-safe and may only be used in a single-threaded context.

Comment: Weder wird der Begriff `eingleisig` verwendet, noch würde ich ihn empfehlen, aber wenn ich einen neuen, nichtfremdsprachlichen Begriff erfinden sollte, würde ich `eingleisig` wählen. Ich kenne zwar den Gesprächsfaden und Erzählstränge die parallel verlaufen können, aber der Ursprung des Fadenbildes ist mir unklar. Sind es Webstühle, vielleicht? Da der Begriff von niemandem verstanden würde poste ich ihn nicht als Antwort.

Comment: Mir hilft oftmals auch das [Microsoft Sprachenportal](http://www.microsoft.com/language/de-de/Search.aspx?sString=thread&langID=de-de).

Comment: Leave the documentation in english. Every software developer is supposed to be able to read and understand english documentation. Translations usually end up with a terrible mix of German and English, or, what is worse, with some newly invented German words nobody has ever heard of (see answers below, my favorite is "einfädig" **WTF??**). If you must do it, be sure to leave a reference (like a HTML-link) to the original documentation, so you can help people like me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Das Objekt ist nicht thread-sicher und sollte nur in Single-Thread-Anwendungen verwendet werden.

At least that would be my guess on the most appropriate translation …

Comment: Akzeptiert... :) wenn auch für den Leser etwas verwirrend, wie ich finde. "Anwendung" ist hier mehrdeutig (Kann das "Programm" beschreiben, aber auch den oben genannten "Verwendungskontext"). Die MSDN schreibt es aber genau so. ;)

Comment: Maybe it would be more suitable to translate "context" directly with "Kontext" or "Umfeld","Umgebung" if you want a literal translation.

Comment: In the context of programming and english/german mixtures, we actually speak of "thread-sicher" (not "gesichert" which would be "thread-safed") as a direct translation for thread-safe.

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde das so schreiben:

> Das Objekt ist nicht gegen Nebenläufigkeit gesichert und darf nur in nicht nebenläufigen Kontexten verwendet werde.

Nebenläufigkeit bedeutet engl. *concurrency* und ist etwas allgemeiner als Thread, es schließt z.B. auch Interrupts ein.

Comment: Stimmt... ist auch ne gute Variante :)

Comment: Ich habe das Wort "Nebenläufigkeit" noch nie gesehen, "thread-sicher" dagegen schon. Ist das Ziel alles so einzudeutschen, dass es kein Informatiker mehr erfassen kann? Dann ist die Version gut.

Comment: Für mein Informatiker-Gefühl ist das ein ganz normaler deutscher Begriff: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebenl%E4ufigkeit

Comment: Du willst nicht gegen "Nebenläufigkeit" sichern, sondern gegen Probleme davon (→ [Wettlaufsituationen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_Condition))

Comment: @moose: Gegen Probleme damit, nicht Probleme davon.

Comment: Das es um Probleme geht, ist bei "sichern" implizit klar. Wenn man das auch noch hinschreibt wird's hölzern.

Comment: Ich schlage als Verbesserung *nicht-nebenläufig* mit Bindestrich vor.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve had a course that was held by ACM Fellow [Tichy](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Tichy) about parallel computing. He always wanted to translate everything into good German (he mentioned that most translations/texts in computer science are quite bad, as they use English terms as the writers didn’t know that German ones existed). He used *einfädig* und *mehrfädig* for *single-threaded* and *multithreaded*. He also spoke of *Fäden* for *Threads*.  Although I think that *Threads* is much more common than *Fäden*, it is consistent with the other terms.

Hence, I would translate it like this:

> Das Objekt ist nicht gegen Probleme der Nebenläufigkeit gesichert und darf nur in einfädigen Kontexten verwendet werden.

Alternatively, if you want a translation that uses the common words:

> Das Objekt ist nicht threadsicher und darf nur in Single-Thread-Anwendungen verwendet werden.

Quite often, it is a good idea to take a look at the German Wikipedia to find common translations:

- [Threadsicherheit](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threadsicherheit)
- [Thread](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28Informatik%29)

I recommend to use the first version if you write an academic paper and the second version if you write some software documentation that programmers should read.

Comment: Your first version sounds more like knitting to me.

Comment: According to Prof. Tichy, this should be the case. You can connect something with the word `Faden` besides computer science. It sounded very strange to me at first, too.

Comment: I don't doubt that and I do see the inherent irony of knitting and programming in threads. But I don't think it conveys the information better, easier or more precise just because it is in German. It just seems like a desperate attempt to remove all English leanwords.

Comment: @chaero: Die Angst vor umstandslosen Übersetzungen solcher Begriffe übersieht, dass das Wort Thread für Englischsprachige auch nichts anderes bedeutet als Faden.

Comment: @userunknown Am besten du gehst einfach mal zur nächstgelegenen Informatikerschmiede und versuchst ein Gepräch über Fäden anzufangen, dann wissen wir ja, ob man es besser versteht. Mich würde das Ergebnis jedenfalls interessieren.

Comment: @userunknown: Das mag für die Englischsprachigen auch der Fall sein, aber in der deutschsprachigen IT-Welt ist man mittlerweile gewissermaßen daran gewöhnt, dass Deutsch spezielle Begriffe bietet, die eben auf Deutsch *nicht* synonym mit den allgemeineren deutschen Wörtern verwendet werden. Manchmal sind diese Begriffe oft aus dem Englischen übernommene Lehnworte, manchmal aber auch deutsche Worte, die kaum in einem anderen Kontext verwendet werden (wie die hier genannte Nebenläufigkeit).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das Wort "Faden" ist einfach eine auch im Englischen verwendete Metapher, und dass es als Metapher geeignet ist hat nichts mit der Sprache, in der die Metapher benutzt wird, zu tun. In Stoffen gibt es auch parallel laufende Fäden. Ganz üblich ist der Gesprächsfaden, den man wieder aufgenommen hat. Beiläufigkeit ist auch ein etablierter Begriff. Mangelndes Interesse an der Sprache führt wohl zu der Haltung fremde Begriffe als Wunder zu betrachten, die vom Himmel gefallen sind, und die man nicht hinterfragen und anfassen darf. Einerseits erheiternd, andererseits mitleidserregend.

Comment: @userunknown: "Mangelndes Interesse an der Sprache" hätte ich damit nicht in Verbindung gebracht; ich finde es eigentlich positiv, wenn Lehnworte eine spezielle Bedeutung bekommen. Einen zusätzlichen Ausdruck für etwas, was es schon auf Deutsch gibt, ist schließlich normalerweise unnötig, aber spezielle Begriffe mit einer engeren Bedeutung fehlen oft.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das Problem dabei ist, dass nur Leute, die kaum Englisch können, auf die Idee kommen können, dass 'Thread' im Englischen eine spezielle Bedeutung für ein nebenläufiges Programm ist und nicht etwa eine Metapher. Das sollte eigentlich nur bei Sprachen passieren, die hier kaum jmd. kennt.

Comment: @userunknown: Vollkommen richtig. Aber im Deutschen ist dies nun mal anders, sodass 'Thread' im Deutschen ohne Weiteres eine spezielle Bedeutung angenommen hat, nämlich die für ein nebenläufiges Programm, und zudem auch die eines Diskussionfadens in einem digitalen Forum. Kaum jemand würde auf Deutsch sagen: "Ich nähe mit Nadel und Thread.", ebenso wäre die Verwendung von "Thread" im Deutschen für einen allgemeinen Diskussionsfaden in einer mündlichen Diskussion fragwürdig.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das hat aber auch niemand behauptet, ist ergo ein Strawman!elf.

Answer (score -4):

> Das Objekt ist nicht instanzensicher und sollte daher nur in einer Instanz verwendet werden.

I’m a native German (developer) and I think this sounds much better then the most proposals here.

Comment: Als langjähriger Programmierer habe ich den Begriff *Instanzen-sicher* noch nie gehört, außerdem würde ich ihn auch als fachlich nicht ganz korrekt empfinden.

Comment: Dass von einer Klasse nur ein Objekt threadsicher erzeugt werden kann ist zwar ein Spezialfall von Threadsicherheit, aber nicht der einzige.